# How fix Non-static method

Tags: java, android, dialog

this is my code in android studio and I can't fix this
[image]

Comment: Just write `alertDialog` instead of `AlertDialog`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `alertDialog` (i.e. `alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Box")`) instead of `AlertDialog` (or however your class is called) and it should work fine..!

*you need to create an instance of a class to be able to call the method properly*

(this holds generally in Java - you can only call static methods without creating the object previously..)

in your case the method `setTitle` is not static so you need to call it via the instance you previously created

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create an instance of the AlertDialog writing something like:

`AlertDialog alertDialogInstance = alertDialog.build();`

then you can call `alertDialogInstance.setTitle("title");`

Comment: n.b. The line above in the screenshot instantiates an `AlertDialog.Builder`.